# Firebase: stopping spam to my database

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have a webapp in which preferably I would like users to be able to interact with without having to sign up. Although there are many features, let's consider one: clicking a "like" button - I would like users to only be able to click "like" once. Without user accounts, my Firebase is open to spam (someone could get the url to my Firebase and constantly submit data to my database; the only thing that prevented this was client code, but the spammer could easily bypass it by running their code elsewhere).

So I considered Firebase's anonymous accounts feature; each anonymous account would only be able to vote once during their session and I would store votes on user local storage. This too can be bypassed if a spammer constantly makes a new anonymous account and clears their storage. In fact, they wouldn't have to clear their storage as the storage check occurs in client code, which is easily bypassable.

So now I am considering Firebase's email account feature. As I was coding it, I realized what stops a spammer from entering a ton of fake email addresses? This could fill up my db quick with unnecessary accounts and also could lead to spam of the "like" button. Does Firebase check if the email is valid? Would Firebase send a confirmation email that the user would have to verify?

Comment: did you manage to get a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**Firebase provides email verification feature.** [Send Verification code to user's email id.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email)
You can use it to verify the user's email. It will send a unique token to the user's email. Firebase authentication sets a flag for email verified. You can check it on your landing page and if it's set to false do not allow user to perform any task. Unless the user clicks on that token, the flag will remain set as false.